# How to target only one row between set of dates in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm new to Google Sheets, but I'm trying to take a row where the current day falls between two dates and highlight that week (or row). Here is a screenshot of my table: https://www.screencast.com/t/CF0OUXU05fj.

I feel like there is some date function/formula that I'm missing here. I tried a couple of variations of the "AND" function, but it highlights all the rows before or after. I also can't change or modify the existing table since other data is being pulled from it.

Here is the formula I currently have, but it doesn't highlight any rows:

```
=AND($A:$A>=TODAY(), $B:$B<=TODAY())
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to hightlight the rows where `today()` is between the startdate (col A) and the enddate (col B), try as a custom formula in conditional formatting.

```
=AND($A24<=today(), $B24 >=today())
```

Where "24" represents the row number where you are checking. It is assumed that your format target range is in the same row as the ones used for validation.
So the above formula assumes the range to apply the format to starts at row 24. (eg. "A24:Z300").

Change range to suit.